# Highlighting text in a div, which is loaded via AJAX

Tags: jquery

I have a div element, which is loaded via AJAX. Once it's loaded, I want to highlight the text in it (the usual process, click your mouse and drag to highlight).

But since DOM is already loaded, the mouse related events are not registered for these new div's, right?

If I have a div like this

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

And after jQuery "get" call, it becomes

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Hello this content is loaded via AJAX</div>
</div>
```

How do I rebind the div "#child" to mouse-related events? And exactly which events do I rebind them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$("#child").live({
    click: function() {
        // do stuff
    },
    mouseover: function() {
        // do stuff
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Bind as many events as you like!

Comment: hm. I think I get that. but exactly which mouse events do I have to "bind" so that I can highlight the text again?

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue, are you not able to select the text that is loaded using AJAX? Unless you've got some other code you don't need to bind anything to have that functionality, the browser handles it for you, dynamically loaded or not.

Comment: Hi Radu, yes I mean "highlight text" = "select text" (that is, press the mouse button and then drag to select). I copied and pasted what you suggested, but I still can't select the text! Not sure what is going on. Does this code propagate to all its child divs too?

Comment: @ebae, I can't think of an issue that could prevent you from doing that. Do you have `user-select:none` in your CSS or are you tampering with `.onselectstart` in your JS?

Comment: no..... this is weird. So are you saying if I use the above code, without anything inside "function()" (where you wrote the //do stuff), it should work right?

Comment: @Radu I think I know what the problem is. I had one of the jQuery UI component on the div as well, and it's preventing me from highlighting text for some reason. More investigation to follow from here. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @ebae, no problem. Bottom line is you don't need to take care of the ability to select text unless you mess it up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For binding events to dynamically loaded contents use jquery .live refer officially documentation as follows
http://api.jquery.com/live/